# Is there a way to get the download path of a browser via Angular 6/7

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, download

Is there anyway to get browser set download path using Angular 6/7? or Is there anyway to download a file to custom location using Angular 6/7?

Currently I am using file-saver "saveAs" function in order to save files, But i need to get download location selection for saving files. I have gone through many links that saying it is not possible due to security constraints. Is there any chance to achieve that?

Comment: It's a browser specific setting. Websites/apps do not have access it. Imagine having a specific setting in the browser and trying to download something from a website and it behaves differently than your setting. This is one of the very mild implication of such behavior. There are also severe security related implications if websites are allowed to access browser settings.

Comment: But in some cases we can see that while downloading it asks for location to save. Can we achieve that?

Comment: It's a browser specific setting. `in some cases` - in these cases the user has set the download behavior to ask for the save location every time. Open your browser options/settings and type `download` in the search field and see the list of options available.